# How to calculate Swing Strength Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

I am working a bowling game for mobile devices and I want the controls to be like the Wii Remote when playing Bowling on the Wii console. I have an idea on the algorithm but I want anyone to verify if this is the correct way to do this.

What I want to archive. Player, presses and holds on to mobile device touch screen, swings the phone and release finger from touch screen. When released, calculations will be done using the device accelerometer, time user touched the screen and time user released the button.
Bellow is what I am currently thinking with a pseudo code.

1) User presses and holds the touch screen.

```
   float pressTime = currentTime;
   float pressAccelerometer = currentAccelerometer;
```

2) User swings the phone forward

3) Player releases their finger from the touch screen.

```
   float releaseTime = currentTime;
   float releasedAccelerometer = currentAccelerometer.
```

4) Calculate throw strength(This is the part that is confusing me)

```
   int throwModifier = 2; //To scale the throwStrength value up
   float throwStrength = (releaseTime-pressTime) *(releasedAccelerometer-pressAccelerometer)*throwModifier ;
```

I failed at step 4. I don't even think that's right. Any ideas on a possible algorithm that could work?

Comment: well for one you're going to be dealing with multiple force vectors, your going to need to combine these (say the down and forward ones) into a single vector (that represents the bottom of the swing when they release the ball).  You also need the ball mass some where (F=ma), i.e. ball mass * accelerometer vector will be the force applied.  I *think* you'll only need to read the accelerometer when they stop pressing the screen.  i.e. you dont care what it started at.

Comment: You shouldn't need the poll, when they stop pressing is when you do the force calculation.  Any previous values are irrelevant, unless you wanted a visible indication of acceleration increasing.

Comment: My bad. I didn't finish my last comment. From what you said, it looks like I need to constantly poll and read the accelerometer then store the value in a temporary variable. Old values from the accelerometer will be overwritten with new accelerometer value. When the user starts to swing the phone, the accelerometer movement will be high and the current value can be used as the startSwingValue. If the finger is release from touch, it will get the current accelerometer  value and then do the calculations. The reason for this is to determine how fast the user swung the phone just like the wiimote

Comment: Also, without that value it wont look natural and real. Determining the speed of the swing will be almost impossible. If the user starts to swing then stops without releasing their finger, the start value will reset automatically. If you've played bowling on the Wii, you will understand what I am saying. So the startvalue is when the swing begins Not when the screen is pressed.

Comment: I can see from a UI point of view, but I'm not sure the swing speed is relevant to the calculations of the force exerted on the ball, your swing accelerates the ball, but you only need the resulting acceleration when they let go to work out how fast they 'bowled' the ball.  Also if you want speed your going to want the start and finish locations, not sure phones have that accurate locationing.